# Python regex - match a number of times

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am wanting to match a character a specific number of times.
For example, I am wanting to match an author's name in a HTML string that looks like this:

```
base>"author's name"</span>
```

The following regex matches any character in between "base>" and "/span>" and returns only the author's name:

```
base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>)
```

However, the HTML file contains 50 instances of this and the above regex returns all 50 matches. How would I modify it so that only the first 10 instances of the matches are returned?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Just get all of them and only consider the first 10.

Comment: You can limit the matches to "n" by using the syntax {n} after the whole expression, so that would be "(base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>)){10}"

Comment: @AhmedAshrafGamal wouldn't that match the string 10 times sequentially? And not anywhere in the text?

Comment: @BartFriederichs you're right, I thought that was the case, if it isn't then yes like you said considering the first 10 result of the matches will be the way to go.

Comment: You could use `finditer` and `break` at the 10th match.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a regex that captures the first ten instances of that regex by concatenating it after itself delimited by `.*?`. You can then use the first ten capture groups to extract the authors:

`base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>).*?base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>).*?base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>).*?base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>).*?base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>).*?base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>).*?base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>).*?base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>).*?base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>).*?base>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<\/span>)`

This is however not what you usually want to do as it makes it relatively hard to change the number of authors you search for. Finding all captures and using only the first few might be more CPU intensive but will make it easier to respond to changing requirements.